# How to convert java.util.Date to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, json, rest, xmlgregoriancalendar

I am converting a SOAP WS to REST WS for Client. Now in Datatype Objects have field which return type is XMLGregorianCalendar.

As I need to keep the Input/Output structure same, so I cannot change any variable names as well their return type.

In Rest WS, we are using json objects as return.

Process :- We sent input to dto and then call procedure, got response from procedure in java.util.date format.
Now I need to change this java.util.date (Numbers) to Date having same format like XMLGregorianCalendar.

Thanks for Help in advance.

I have tried the following code.

changed the DTO variable return type to java.util.Date

```
private Date informeFechaDlgncmnto;

@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateTimeSerializer.class)
public Date getInformeFechaDlgncmnto() {
    return informeFechaDlgncmnto;
}

public void setInformeFechaDlgncmnto(Date informeFechaDlgncmnto) {
    this.informeFechaDlgncmnto = informeFechaDlgncmnto;
}
```

JsonDateTimeSerializer Class

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

@Override
public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);

    gen.writeString(formattedDate);
}
```

> Current output for REST WS :-
>
> "informeFechaDlgncmnto": "2019-04-09T12:20:44.000",

SOAP WS Code

variable in DTO

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar informeFechaDlgncmnto;

public XMLGregorianCalendar getInformeFechaDlgncmnto() {
    return informeFechaDlgncmnto;
}

public void setInformeFechaDlgncmnto(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    this.informeFechaDlgncmnto = value;
}
```

Code to change in gregorianCalendar in Servicelayer

```
private ConsultaFuratRespType addTZInformeFechaDlgncmnto(
        ConsultaFuratRespType consultaFuratRespType) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone
                .getTimeZone("UTC-0700";));

        Calendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(
                TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-0700";));

        gregorianCalendar = consultaFuratRespType.getData().getDatosFurat()
                .getInformeFechaDlgncmnto().toGregorianCalendar();

        String gregorianCalendarString = simpleDateFormat
                .format(gregorianCalendar.getTime());

        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(gregorianCalendarString);

        GregorianCalendar gregCalInformeFechaDlgncmnto = new GregorianCalendar(
                TimeZone.getTimeZone(ConstantesApp.TIMEZONE_UTC_MINUS_5000));

        gregCalInformeFechaDlgncmnto = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar
                .getInstance();

        gregCalInformeFechaDlgncmnto.setTime(date);

        consultaFuratRespType.getData().getDatosFurat()
                .setInformeFechaDlgncmnto(gregCalInformeFechaDlgncmnto);

        return consultaFuratRespType;
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        return consultaFuratRespType;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return consultaFuratRespType;
    }
```

> Output in SOAPUI
>
> 2019-04-09T12:20:44.0-05:00

The Output should be same.

> Current Output :-
>
> SOAP WS :- 2019-04-09T12:20:44.0-05:00
>
> REST WS :- 2019-04-09T12:20:44.000